# Importing cookies.txt to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I know this isn't a programming question, but I have googled it everywhere and all I can see is importing a json file or something else.

I had exported it as a txt file and now I don't know how to import it. I can no longer export it as some other file. I had used that Cookies.txt extension on chrome.

So what way can I import my cookies.txt file to Chrome or even FireFox.

Comment: Since the only helpful answer has been deleted, if anyone's looking for an extension to import cookies.txt in Chrome, use this: https://github.com/zhad3/cookies.txt-importer-for-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different Cookie managers on FireFox I found this one Advanced Cookie Manager, that imported the txt file. Still can't find a way to import txt on Chrome though.